# Large UIImage not scaling down into Scroll View's frame

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage, contentmode

i can't seem to use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit property to scale my imageView within my scrollview to fit the scrollview size.

```
- (void)loadView {
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.moilum.com/images/atomicongallery/setmenu/setmenu1.jpg"]]];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:applicationFrame];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.3;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
scrollView.delegate = self;
self.view = scrollView;
```

}

i have tried imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill as well. scrollView.contentmode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill as well. All dont seem to work :(

any way out!?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIScrollView will not adjust its zoomScale if you don't implement the `- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)sView` method on the UIScrollViewDelegate.

Something like this

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)sView 
{
  NSArray *subViews = [sView subviews];
  if([subViews count] > 0){
     return [subViews objectAtIndex:0];
  }
  return nil;
}
```

(But apparently not setting a delegate at all works too.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried,

```
-(void)loadView
{
      CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrolllView.frame.size.height);
      imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
      imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"];
      imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
      [scrollView addSubView:imageView];
      scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
 }
```

I write this code from my iPad i think this should work,
Let me know if you have any problem.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Jecht, your code works! i Found the problem. whenever i set the delegate to the scrollview. the imageview doesnt resize itself to the contentmode as set. Something in the scrollview.delegate stops that from happening. Also i think it could be the method viewforScrollView which i implemented which doesnt let the imageview resize. thanks :)